# How to generate alert when entered qty is more than available stock

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have created one IMS System. In that my stock is going in negative and I have to stop it so my main intention is to generate the alert when the entered product is more than available stock(Ex. if a user is entering 12 qty and in stock only available is 10 qty than alert message should generate like entered quantity is more than available stock so you can't generate order).Below is my code

```
public function create()
    {
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT bill_no FROM orders ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
        $result = $query->row()->bill_no;
        $result++;
        //echo $result;
        //end();
        //$curYear = date('Y');
        $invoice_no = $result;
        //$invoice['invoice_no'] = $invoice_no;
        $data = array(
            'po_no' => $this->input->post('po_no'),
            'po_date' => $this->input->post('po_date'),
            'challan_no' => $this->input->post('challan_no'),
            'challan_date' => $this->input->post('challan_date'),
            'bill_no' => $invoice_no,
            'bill_date' => $this->input->post('bill_date'),
            'terms' => $this->input->post('terms'),
            'dispatch' => $this->input->post('dispatch'),
            'party_id' => $this->input->post('id'),
            'name' => $this->input->post('name_value'),
            'address' => $this->input->post('address_value'),
            'gstin' => $this->input->post('gstin_value'),
            'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile_value'),
            'date_time' => strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s a')),
            'qty' => $this->input->post('qty_value'),
            'gross_amount' => $this->input->post('gross_amount_value'),
            'central_amount' => $this->input->post('central_amount_value'),
            'net_amount' => $this->input->post('net_amount_value'),
            'round_amount' =>$this->input->post('round_amount_value'),
            'round_amount_words' => $this->input->post('round_amount_words'),
            'paid_status' => 2,
            'user_id' => $user_id
        );
        $insert = $this->db->insert('orders', $data);
        $order_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        $this->load->model('model_products');

        $count_product = count($this->input->post('product'));
        for($x = 0; $x < $count_product; $x++) {
            $items = array(
                'order_id' => $order_id,
                'product_id' => $this->input->post('product')[$x],
                'hsn' => $this->input->post('hsn_value')[$x],
                'rate' => $this->input->post('rate')[$x],
                'qty' => $this->input->post('qty')[$x],
                'unit' => $this->input->post('unit_value')[$x],
                'amount' => $this->input->post('amount_value')[$x],
                'gst' => $this->input->post('gst_value')[$x],
                'gst_amount' => $this->input->post('gst_amount_value')[$x],
                'last_amount' => $this->input->post('last_amount_value')[$x],
            );

            $this->db->insert('orders_item', $items);

            // now decrease the stock from the product
            $product_data = $this->model_products->getProductData($this->input->post('product')[$x]);
            $qty = (int) $product_data['qty'] - (int) $this->input->post('qty')[$x];

            $update_product = array('qty' => $qty);


            $this->model_products->update($update_product, $this->input->post('product')[$x]);
        }

        return ($order_id) ? $order_id : false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried counting product quantity before the order is made?

Comment: 'qty' => $this->input->post('qty')[$x] this line gives the product quantity

Comment: Maybe you should just return `false` straight if the product count is less than the order placed even before going further

Comment: Now what should I do to resolve my problem

Comment: Have you resolved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your `product_model`, you could add a method to return the product count.

```
class Products_model extends CI_Model
{
  ...
  /**
   * Returns product quantity in db
   * @param string $product_id
   * @return integer
   */
  public function productQty($product_id)
  {
    $qty = $this->db->query("SELECT `qty` FROM `products`"
            . " WHERE product_id = `$product_id` ...")->result_array();
    return (int) $qty[0]['qty'];
  }
  ...
}
```

Then in your `create()` above, you can just check if ordered quantity is less than existing quantity.

```
...
for($x = 0; $x < $count_product; $x++) {
  $qtyOrdered = (int) $this->input->post('qty')[$x];
  if ($this->model_products->productQuantity(
    $this->input->post('product')[$x]
  ) < $qtyOrdered) {
    // Quantity is less. Do something like alert concerned people 
  } else {
    // Continue
  }
}
...
```

Comment: My main intention is to check all product quantity in a bill before generating or updating the order (Ex. if 5 items are in an order then after checking all item quantity order should generate or update).According to your answer it is checking individual quantity

Comment: You can loop twice, first to check and second to update. If one iteration in the first fails, you don't proceed but return with a message or something